# What would be an interesting linear bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can anyone give me an example of such an operator (preferably, but not necessary, self-adjoint) on a Hilbert space? Not the usual ones you would find in a textbook (multiplication, integral, shift, etc).

I'd would like to calculate the norm and spectrum of it. Also, ones that aren't on doubly infinite sequence spaces (like discrete Laplace operator) would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the Toeplitz operators on the Hardy-Hilbert space? ($H^2$ on the unit disk).

Comment: Thanks. On first glance they look a bit too complex for me, but I'll have a closer look.